# Mousemove event on React/canvas component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, mouseevent

I'm trying to recreate the exact same effect seen in this Codepen

https://codepen.io/timaikens/pen/ojqPmd?editors=0110

in a React project. Everything but the `mousemove` event seems to be working okay (i.e. the honeycomb is rendered and resizes appropriately). The code I have for the MousetrailCanvas is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class MousetrailCanvas extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.mousetrailRef = React.createRef()

        this.init = this.init.bind(this)
        this.makeHoney = this.makeHoney.bind(this)
    }

    makeHoney(mx, my) {
        const mCtx = this.mousetrailRef.current.getContext('2d')
        const h = mCtx.canvas.height
        const w = mCtx.canvas.width

        mCtx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)

        const yd = 16
        const xd = 2 * yd * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3)
        const xl = mx % xd
        const xr = xd - mx % xd
        const yu = my % (3 * yd)
        const yb = 3 * yd - my % (3 * yd)
        const hlu = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xl, 2) + Math.pow(yu, 2))
        const hlb = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xl, 2) + Math.pow(yb, 2))
        const hru = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xr, 2) + Math.pow(yu, 2))
        const hrb = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xr, 2) + Math.pow(yb, 2))

        mCtx.strokeStyle = '#f3c41b' // `$mustard` in _settings.scss
        mCtx.lineWidth = 1
        mCtx.fillStyle = '#4eb9da' // `$turquoise` in _settings.scss

        let hexCx = null
        let hexCy = null

        if (
            (mx % (2 * xd) < xd && my % (6 * yd) < 3 * yd) ||
            (mx % (2 * xd) > xd && my % (6 * yd) >= 3 * yd)
        ) {
            if (hlu < hrb) {
                hexCx = mx - xl
                hexCy = my - yu
            } else {
                hexCx = mx + xr
                hexCy = my + yb
            }
        } else {
            if (hlb < hru) {
                hexCx = mx - xl
                hexCy = my + yb
            } else {
                hexCx = mx + xr
                hexCy = my - yu
            }
        }

        console.log(hexCx)
        console.log(hexCy)

        mCtx.moveTo(hexCx - xd, hexCy - yd)
        mCtx.beginPath()
        mCtx.lineTo(hexCx, hexCy - 2 * yd)
        mCtx.lineTo(hexCx + xd, hexCy - yd)
        mCtx.lineTo(hexCx + xd, hexCy + yd)
        mCtx.lineTo(hexCx, hexCy + 2 * yd)
        mCtx.lineTo(hexCx - xd, hexCy + yd)
        mCtx.lineTo(hexCx - xd, hexCy - yd)
        mCtx.closePath()
        mCtx.fill()
        mCtx.stroke()
    }

    init(e) {
        let mx = e.clientX
        let my = e.clientY
        this.makeHoney(mx, my)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.mousetrailRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', this.init)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.mousetrailRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.init)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas
                height={this.props.height}
                width={this.props.width}
                className='mousetrail'
                ref={this.mousetrailRef}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

At present nothing at all is happening upon `mousemove` events, but if I click within the canvas element, the calls to `console.log` within the `makeHoney` function do print out the expected results.

Any tips, suggestions as to where I'm going off track would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the `onMouseMove` event to the canvas element itself?

Comment: hmm tested it and it looks fine for me (https://codesandbox.io/s/mz6lowwkwx), I can see 'honey' below cursor while moving it, no need to click anywhere.

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, @user1030150 if I add the event listener directly to the element via `onMouseMove={this.init}`, I can see the calls to `console.log` print out correctly, but still no effect. I'm now truly baffled :/

Comment: So the sandbox posted by user1030150 works fine, meaning there's something different about your setup. Maybe something overriding the styles you want to apply? Or maybe more event listeners outside the component that are in conflict?